# Handling the interacton of intances of classes belong to two parallel inhertiance groups

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have two groups of classes in my code and one group has logic and other group has data and inheritance is also being used in each group. I tried to mimic the situation which I am dealing with in below code snippet. The problem I have is how to handle the objects of derived data classes efficiently in related instances of logic classes. Right now I am trying to cast the instance of derived data class in a method of derived logic class which I do not think is logical. I need some guidance to address this issue.

```
void Main()
{
    var item1 = new D1();
    var holder1 = new DataHolder1() { localProp1 = "test" };
    var holderout = item1.Method1(holder1);
    holderout.Dump();

}



public class BaseDataHolder
{
    public string prop { get; set; }
}

public class DataHolder1 : BaseDataHolder
{
    public string localProp1 { get; set; }
}


public class DataHolder2 : BaseDataHolder
{
    public string localProp2 { get; set; }
}


public  class BaseClass
{
    public virtual BaseDataHolder Method1(BaseDataHolder holder)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class D1 : BaseClass
{
    public override BaseDataHolder Method1(BaseDataHolder holder)
    {
        (holder as DataHolder1).localProp1.Dump();
        (holder as DataHolder1).localProp1 = "change1";
        return holder;
    }
}

public class D2 : BaseClass
{
    public override BaseDataHolder Method1(BaseDataHolder holder)
    {
        (holder as DataHolder2).localProp2.Dump();
        (holder as DataHolder2).localProp2 = "change2";
        return holder;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't really match up with your current description here, but something keeps whispering "Visitor Pattern" in my ear.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it would be illogical since looks like you are trying to get `DataHolder1` always in class `D1`. Rather, why can't your class compose with Data class instance and use that in method like

```
public class D1 : BaseClass
{
    private readonly DataHolder1 holder;

    public D1(DataHolder1 holder) { this.holder = holder; }

    public override BaseDataHolder Method1()
    {
        holder.localProp1.Dump();
        holder.localProp1 = "change1";
        return holder;
    }
}
```

Then you can just say

```
var item1 = new D1(new DataHolder1());
BaseDataHolder data = item1.Method1();
```

Comment: I agree with you and this solution will work. However I have few other things due to which I cannot define instance of Holder1 as private field.

Comment: @User1551892 do you mind posting those *few other things* then for better understanding

Comment: Thanks. now I know that I have to make few more changes in architecture of application.

Answer (score 1):

This violates the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). In summary, it's *bad*, because your signature promises to work well with any `BaseDataHolder` but in reality it will just crash if the *wrong* `BaseDataHolder` is passed in.

I cannot really give a solution because we don't know your requirements. From what you have posted, your three logic classes should drop the inheritance and just have three different method signatures, each telling what it needs instead of all of them lying about what they need and then crashing randomly.

Comment: Understood. Problem is, I am trying to add few new functionalities in application similar to one which already exists. It seems that I have to make more changes at low level which I was trying to avoid.